# renaming pcraster mapstack

Tags: python, netcdf

I have a folder filled with 20 years precipitation pcraster mapstack in days, I've managed to extract from the original netcdf file precipitation value for my interest area and rename it into this to avoid confusion

```
precip.19810101 
precip.19810102 
precip.19810103 
precip.19810104 
precip.19810105
...
precip.20111231
```

but after that, I want to rename all of my files into pcraster mapstack based on this sequence of dates

```
precip00.001
precip00.002
precip00.003
precip00.004
...
```

I'm a beginner in python, is there any help or example for me to figure it out how to do this?
Thank you

Comment: just to clarify: sort by name, rename the oldest `.001`, the oldest but one `.002` and so on...? Note: three digits are not enough for 365*20 (and 1981 to 2011 is 30 years, not 20 -which means, you'll need 5 digits.)

Comment: yes, I'm trying to do that and the file name of this pcraster mapstack would be after precip00.999 is precip01.000 ... until precip07.300  And I've made a mistake in the tag it is not batch file, I'm sorry. Thank you @Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I put together, based on some old Python scripts I once wrote:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# Rename PCRaster map stack with names following prefix.yyymmmdd to stack with valid
# PCRaster time step numbers
# Johan van der Knijff
#
# Example input stack:
#
# precip.19810101
# precip.19810102
# precip.19810103
# precip.19810104
# precip.19810105
#
# Then run script with following arguments:
#
# python renpcrstack.py precip 1
#
# Result:
#
# precip00.001
# precip00.002
# precip00.003
# precip00.004
# precip00.005
#

import sys
import os
import argparse
import math
import datetime
import glob

# Create argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Rename map stack")

def parseCommandLine():
    # Add arguments
    parser.add_argument('prefix',
                        action="store",
                        type=str,
                        help="prefix of input map stack (also used as output prefix)")
    parser.add_argument('stepStartOut',
                        action="store",
                        type=int,
                        help="time step number that is assigned to first map in output stack")

    # Parse arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return(args)

def dateToJulianDay(date):

    # Calculate Julian Day from date
    # Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Converting_Julian_or_Gregorian_calendar_date_to_Julian_day_number

    a = (14 - date.month)/12
    y = date.year + 4800 - a
    m = date.month +12*a - 3

    JulianDay = date.day + math.floor((153*m + 2)/5) + 365*y + math.floor(y/4) \
        - math.floor(y/100) + math.floor(y/400) - 32045

    return(JulianDay)

def genStackNames(prefix,start,end, stepSize):
    # Generate list with names of all maps
    # map name is made up of 11 characters, and chars 8 and 9 are
    # separated by a dot. Name starts with prefix, ends with time step
    # number and all character positions in between are filled with zeroes

    # define list that will contain map names
    listMaps = []

    # Count no chars prefix
    charsPrefix = len(prefix)

    # Maximum no chars needed for suffix (end step)
    maxCharsSuffix = len(str(end))

    # No of free positions between pre- and suffix
    noFreePositions = 11 - charsPrefix - maxCharsSuffix

    # Trim prefix if not enough character positions are available 
    if noFreePositions < 0:
        # No of chars to cut from prefix if 11-char limit is exceeded
        charsToCut = charsPrefix + maxCharsSuffix - 11
        charsToKeep = charsPrefix - charsToCut

        # Updated prefix
        prefix = prefix[0:charsToKeep]

        # Updated prefix length
        charsPrefix = len(prefix)

    # Generate name for each step

    for i in range(start,end + 1,stepSize):

        # No of chars in suffix for this step
        charsSuffix = len(str(i))

        # No of zeroes to fill
        noZeroes = 11 - charsPrefix - charsSuffix

        # Total no of chars right of prefix
        charsAfterPrefix = noZeroes + charsSuffix

        # Name of map

        thisName = prefix + (str(i)).zfill(charsAfterPrefix)
        thisFile = thisName[0:8]+"." + thisName[8:11]

        listMaps.append(thisFile)

    return listMaps    

def main():
    # Parse command line arguments
    args = parseCommandLine()
    prefix = args.prefix
    stepStartOut = args.stepStartOut

    # Glob pattern for input maps: prefix + dot + 8 char extension
    pattern = prefix + ".????????"

    # Get list of all input maps based on glob pattern
    mapsIn = glob.glob(pattern)

    # Set time format
    tfmt = "%Y%m%d"

    # Set up dictionary that will act as lookup table between Julian Days (key) 
    # and Date string
    jDayDate = {}

    for map in mapsIn:
        baseNameIn = os.path.splitext(map)[0]
        dateIn = os.path.splitext(map)[1].strip(".")

        # Convert to date / time format
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateIn, tfmt)

        # Convert date to Julian day number
        jDay = int(dateToJulianDay(dt))

        # Store as key-value pair in dictionary
        jDayDate[jDay] = dateIn

    # Number of input maps (equals number of key-value pairs)
    noMaps = len(jDayDate)

    # Create list of names for output files 
    mapNamesOut = genStackNames(prefix, stepStartOut, noMaps + stepStartOut -1, 1)

    # Iterate over Julian Days (ascending order)

    i = 0

    for key in sorted(jDayDate):
        # Name of input file
        fileIn = prefix + "."+ jDayDate[key]

        # Name of output file
        fileOut = mapNamesOut[i]

        # Rename file
        os.rename(fileIn, fileOut)

        print("Renamed " + fileIn + " ---> " + fileOut)

        i += 1

main()
```

(Alternatively download the code from [my Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/bitsgalore/bfb3201aae2586689148).)

You can run it from the command line, using the prefix of your map stack and the number of the first output map as arguments, e.g.:

```
python renpcrmaps.py precip 1
```

Please note that the script renames the files in place, so make sure to make a copy of your original map stack in case something goes wrong (I only did some *very* limited testing on this!).

Also, the script assumes a non-sparse input map stack, i.e. in case of daily maps, an input map exists for *each* day. In case of missing days, the numbering of the output maps will not be what you'd expect.

The internal conversion of all dates to Julian Days may be a bit overkill here, but once you start doing more advanced transformations it does make things easier because it gives you decimal numbers which are more straightforward to manipulate than date strings.

Comment: Thanks @johan the script works for one month, will try to do it for a longer period.

Answer (score 0):

as you gave the `[batch-file]` tag, I assume, Batch is ok:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counti=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /on precip.*') do (
  set /a counti+=1
  set "counts=000000000!counti!"
  ECHO ren "%%a" "precip!counts:~-6,3!.!counts:~-3!"
)
```

remove the `ECHO` after successfully checking the Output

**EDITED** to match your `precip00.999 is precip01.000 ... until precip07.300` requirement (in your question it's `precip000.001` in your comment it's `precip00.001` - I decided to use the first Format, can easily be changed to `ECHO ren "%%a" "precip!counts:~-5,2!.!counts:~-3!"` for the second Format.). Although it's not `Batch` anymore, I'll leave the answer, maybe you can at least use the logic.

If you are not firm with Batch, the `%variable:~-6,3%` Syntax is explained with `set /?`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue a short while ago. Please note I am new both to python and PCRaster so do not take me example without check.

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch
import subprocess
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from shutil import copyfile

TipeofFile = 'precip.????????' # original file   
Files = []
for iListFile in sorted(os.listdir('.')):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(iListFile, TipeofFile):
        Files.append(iListFile)

digiafter = 3 #after the point: .001, .002, 0.003
digitTotal = 8 #total: precipi00000.000 (5.3)
for j in xrange(0, len(Files)):
    num = str(j + 1)    
    nameFile = Files[j]
    putZeros = digitTotal - len(num)
    for x in xrange(0,putZeros):
        num = "0" + num
    precip = num[0:digitTotal-digiafter]+ '.' +num[digitTotal-digiafter:digitTotal]
    precip = str(precip)    
    precip = 'precip' + precip 

    copyfile(nameFile, precip)
```